# Hibernate: ScrollableResults + Order

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created Criteria with some order:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(MyEntity.SOME_PROPERTY));
ScrollableResults scrollableResults = criteria.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
List<MyEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(scrollableResults.next()) {
   list.add(scrollableResults.get(0));
}
```

Will MyEntities from `list` be sorted by `SOME_PROPERTY`?

Comment: Seems we don't get you. Try to rephrase your question what is your problem.

Comment: Hello, done:) I hope now it more clear.

Comment: The easiest way is to execute your code and see the result (use System.out.println temporary to see the result then remove it)  :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Until you know whether or not you have a problem, please don't post a question.